# Чтение определенных столбцов из CSV по названию столбцов

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Есть csv-файл 1Гб, с 80к предикторов, 10к наблюдений, некоторые наблюдения битые, поэтому нужно использовать `error_bad_lines=False` . Из всех 80к признаков, меня интересуют все признаки имеющие в имени строку `executions`. 
Как можно прочитать csv, не перегружая память и выводя ТОЛЬКО нужные столбцы в DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

сначала читаем только одну строку с заголовками (именами) столбцов

```
In [239]: cols = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=0).columns

In [240]: cols
Out[240]: Index(['id', 'executions_01', 'another_01', 'executions_02', 'another_02', 'executions_03', 'another_03'], dtype='object')
```

получим список нужных нам полей:

```
In [243]: cols = cols[cols.str.contains('executions_')].tolist()

In [244]: cols
Out[244]: ['executions_01', 'executions_02', 'executions_03']
```

теперь можем читать только нужные поля, сэкономив память:

```
In [248]: df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=cols, error_bad_lines=False)

In [249]: df
Out[249]:
   executions_01  executions_02  executions_03
0              1              1              1
1              2              2              2
2              3              3              3
```

---

> как вписать ИЛИ в условие паттернов? "executions || id"?

```
In [31]: cols = cols[cols.str.contains('(?:^id$|executions_)')].tolist()

In [32]: cols
Out[32]: ['id', 'executions_01', 'executions_02', 'executions_03']
```

тестовый CSV файл:

```
id,executions_01,another_01,executions_02,another_02,executions_03,another_03
1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2,2,2
3,3,3,3,3,3,3
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает хорошо!

Comment: а как вписать ИЛИ в условие паттернов? "executions || id"?